# Crystal reports formula for multiple scenarios

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a report that needs to print data if the following conditions happen if the number is 12, 24 print data ( using a filter to get this right now)  or if the number changes to 12 or 24 print data or if number changes and leaves 12, 24 print data. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us what your data looks like? Do you have a before/after column or do you need to pull both the before and after records?

If the first scenario you can use a record selection formula along these lines:

```
{mytable.oldnumber} in [12, 24] or
{mytable.newnumber} in [12, 24]
```